# How to save telnet output logs to a text file

Tags: python-3.x, networking, network-programming, telnet, telnetlib

hi guys please how can I   save the output logs to text file  for this         script to solve this problem

```
    import sys
    import telnetlib
    import getpass
    #####################
    ###### Define Host
    host=["192.168.1.164","192.168.1.169"]
    devno=len(host)
    user='ali'
    Password='cisco'

    for i in range(devno):
        print('*'*50 + ' Connected to device : '+str(host[i]) +'*'*50)
        tn=telnetlib.Telnet(host[i])
        tn.read_until(b'Username: ')
        tn.write(user.encode('ascii')+ b'\n')
        tn.read_until(b'Password')
        tn.write(Password.encode('ascii')+b'\n')
        #tn.write(b'enable' + b'\n')
        #tn.write(b"\n")
        #tn.write(b"terminal length 0\n")
        #tn.write(b"show run\n")
        #tn.write(b' show ip route\n')
        tn.write(b'  exit\n')
        print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.hussein

Comment: I mean I want to save the output of the file your code it open the file without save any output

Answer (score 0):

you could add this at the end of your for loop

```
    with open("text1.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(str(tn.read_all().decode("ascii")))
```

the above should save the output of your commands to the file

if you want to get the logs as well then you need to add the following just before you exit

```
    tn.write(b' show log\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Hussein it open the file in the same directory but does not save the logs to the file just empty file .

Comment: I try now your command it work open the file but the logs not save to the file

Comment: @aliabd please check my answer, I updated it... it all depends on the commands you use

Comment: I check and try it is working to create file but not save the output to the file